# How to increase int value in Java?

Tags: java, android

Let's say I increase the integer value here from 0 - 100.

```
public void onProgressChanged(int progress) {
    percentageMeasurer(progress);
}
```

And I read it like to that, to save it afterwards:

```
int someValue = 0;
public void percentageMeasurer(int currentProgress) {
    int someValue = currentProgress);
}
```

The problem is, `onProgressChanged` will be excecuted twice, so the value of someValue will always become 100, I would like to add these two values, so the sum would be in the end 200, but of course it starts overwrite it the next time `onProgressChanged` is excuted.

Comment: If you're calling `onProgressChanged` only twice total (both times when it hits 100), is there no reason why you can't do `someValue += currentProgress`?

Comment: public void onProgressChanged(int progress) {
progress =  someValue ;
}

Comment: You're shadowing your variable in your method, for starters - give removing the `int` declaration in the method a go and see how that works out.

Comment: @k0sh won't that code basically be a no-op?

Comment: You should use Encapsulation here .. try updating your int from within a method and apply your logic from that method.

Comment: Please post code that doesn't actually fail to compile with a syntax error. Ideally, explain why you thought the code should be working, and what you really want to achieve. It's unclear from the question at present. What calls `onProgressChanged`? What values does it receive? Why should the receiver of the call have to sum them up?

Comment: Am I missing something or are you asking how to use `+` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may accomplish what you want:

```
int someValue = 0;
public void percentageMeasurer(int currentProgress) {
     someValue += currentProgress;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you could just use two separate variables as the two instances of the onProgressChanged and then add them separatly.